# Having problems coding if and counter

Tags: php, if-statement

I am trying to figure out how to do two things. One Query a database and get a record count (NO PROBLEM WITH THIS) Next I want to display a limited number of record on a webpage. this is where I get stuck. I am pretty sure I need to add a counter to the while loop but I keep having a problem only displaying one record 1000's of times.

```
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    echo "<center><table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>Legal Business Name</th>";
    echo "<th>DBA Name</th>";
    echo "<th>Business Address</th>";
    echo "<th>Website  Address</th>";
    echo "<th>Business Government POC</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {                  
    echo  "<tr><td>" . $row["LEGAL_BUSINESS_NAME"]. "</td>";
    echo  "<td>" . $row["DBA_NAME"]. "</td>";
    echo  "<td>" . $row["PHYSICAL_ADDRESS_LINE_1"]. "<br>" . $row["PHYSICAL_ADDRESS_LINE_2"]. "<br>" . $row["PHYSICAL_ADDRESS_CITY"]. ", " . $row["PHYSICAL_ADDRESS_PROVINCE_OR_STATE"]. " " . $row["PHYSICAL_ADDRESS_ZIP_POSTAL_CODE"]. "+" . $row["PHYSICAL_ADDRESS_ZIP_CODE_PLUS_4"]. " " . $row["PHYSICAL_ADDRESS_COUNTRY_CODE"]. "</td>";
   echo  "<td>" . $row["CORPORATE_URL"]. "</td>";
   echo  "<td>" . $row["GOVT_BUS_POC_FIRST_NAME"]. " " . $row["GOVT_BUS_POC_MIDDLE_INITIAL"]. " " . $row["GOVT_BUS_POC_LAST_NAME"]. "<br> P: ". $row["GOVT_BUS_POC_US_PHONE"]. "<br> E: ". $row["GOVT_BUS_POC_EMAIL"]. "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";                    
}
   echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Why not use LIMIT in SQL?

Comment: I am selling records in a database there could be 10000 records but I only want to display 10 records as a sample. if I limit in the select statement I don't get the full count.

Comment: Well, that's a good thing. You should never fetch all the data just to get the count. Use `COUNT()` in SQL instead

Comment: I am not fetching all the data for a count it will be written to a file. I am just trying to figure out how to display only the first 10 records.

Answer (score -1):

Ok I figured this out. Sometimes you need a bigger hammer!

I added in a counter and created an if statement right after the while loop.

```
$int = 0;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if ($int < 10) {
        echo  "<tr><td>" . $row["LEGAL_BUSINESS_NAME"]. "</td>";
        echo  "<td>" . $row["DBA_NAME"]. "</td>";
        echo  "<td>" . $row["PHYSICAL_ADDRESS_LINE_1"]. "<br>" . $row["PHYSICAL_ADDRESS_LINE_2"]. "<br>" . $row["PHYSICAL_ADDRESS_CITY"]. ", " . $row["PHYSICAL_ADDRESS_PROVINCE_OR_STATE"]. " " . $row["PHYSICAL_ADDRESS_ZIP_POSTAL_CODE"]. "+" . $row["PHYSICAL_ADDRESS_ZIP_CODE_PLUS_4"]. " " . $row["PHYSICAL_ADDRESS_COUNTRY_CODE"]. "</td>";
        echo  "<td>" . $row["CORPORATE_URL"]. "</td>";
        echo  "<td>" . $row["GOVT_BUS_POC_FIRST_NAME"]. " " . $row["GOVT_BUS_POC_MIDDLE_INITIAL"]. " " . $row["GOVT_BUS_POC_LAST_NAME"]. "<br> P: ". $row["GOVT_BUS_POC_US_PHONE"]. "<br> E: ". $row["GOVT_BUS_POC_EMAIL"]. "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        $int = $int + 1;
    }
}
```